# Pymongo returns connection refused

Tags: flask, docker-compose, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to connect Monogdb to my flask application. But I keep getting this connection error.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: csmongodb:27018: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Below are the details:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient(app.config['MONGODB_URI'],tls=MONGODB_USE_TLS,tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True)
database = client.test_db
client.drop_database(test_db)
```

The MONOGODB_URI format I followed is following:

```
mongodb://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}
```

My docker compose file is something like this:

```
csmongodb:
    container_name: "cs_mongodb_1"
    image: "mongo:3.6-xenial"
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    volumes:
      - csmongodb:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
    networks:
      - "backend"
```

I am using pymongo version 3.9.0

Comment: What hostname is in your connection URL?

Comment: @BellyBuster csmongodb